# Variable set in timer is accessible in display, but can't be as an input to a method

Tags: c#, timer

I am using a timer to create a variable (`Amp_current`); this variable is correctly displayed in a label box I've put in the window form.

But when I want to use it as an input (`Amp`) to another method in another class, its value is always 0. I don't know why it isn't affected by the timer. My code is as follows.

```
public float Amp;
public float Amp_current;

private float SetAmpStatus(float Amp_current)
{
    double newData2 = Math.Round(Amp_current, 1);
    TBlabel.Text = newData2.ToString();
    TBlabel.Invalidate();
    TBlabel.Update();
    TBlabel.Refresh();  // Here, label box is refreshed correctly
    Amp = Amp_current;
    Application.DoEvents();
    return Amp;    //when I use Amp in another method, its value is always 0 !!!
}
float Amp_0 = 2;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        Amp_current = Amp_0 + 0.2f;
        Amp_0 = Amp_current;
        SetAmpStatus(Amp_current);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    } 
    timer1.Stop();
}


 ourPiezo_Z.piezoCommand(Amp, out piezoZCommand , out stepperCommand);  //using Amp as input argument of a method
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where do you start the timer?

Comment: I've added the timer from toolbox to my form, and in the Properties, set its "Enabled" to"True" and the interval to 15000.

Comment: OK. That means that after 15 seconds the value will be set. You are probably calling the other method too soon. What does it look like and when and how do you call it?

Comment: I put a   Thread.Sleep(15000)  before calling the method. but it didn't work.  The method is called after              ourPiezo_Z.piezoCommand(Amp, out piezoZCommand , out stepperCommand);    The "Amp" input is still 0.

Comment: I still think it is a timing problem. Put the call in a button click for test and you'll see that the Amp variable does get changed.  I doubt that your way of using Timer and Thread.Sleep is right, it sounds like a XY-problem to me, that is it fiddles at the wrong end of the problem..

Comment: _I put a Thread.Sleep(15000) before calling the method._ Where did you put that? The Timer won't run during the Sleep! and what is it you __really__ want to do??

Comment: If you are using [this timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then it'll run on the UI thread. If you also have a `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread, then your timer isn't going to do anything while the thread it's running on is sleeping.

Comment: Also `Application.DoEvents();` is usually a sign that you are doing something wrong. It sounds like you are trying to do something multithreaded without *actually* using multiple threads. Learn about multithreading and do it the right way.

Comment: I suspect your problem stems from some of the bad coding practices you are using. You have the variable `Amp_current` defined twice. Once at the class-level and once in `SetAmpStatus`. Your `timer1_Tick` method is updating the class-level variable `Amp_0`. I suspect that the rest of your code has these kinds of issues and that's why your code isn't working. I think you need to provide us with all of your code to get an answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you all :) I changed the use of timer interval to a smaller value , 50 ms and got rid of "for" loop in the timer.        `if (step1 < 20 ) 
            {
                 Amp_current += 0.1f;
                    step1++;
            }
            else if (step1 == 20) 
            { 
                Amp_current -= 2;
                step1++;
            }`      and it worked. I think the way i used the timer was not logical.